# How to use Document Reference feature of GCP Firestore with Spring Data FireStore?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, spring-data

I'm looking for documentation and examples related to ***document reference*** feature of FireStore with Spring Data Firestore.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you are trying to do? Where do you want to use the Document Reference?

Comment: @Prabir I have two collections called Tenants & Users, In Users collection I need to have a document reference pointing to a data in tenants collection. I could very well add Users collection as part of tenants collection due to some design requirements I'm not choosing it. Let me know if you need more details!

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/e9c08349432e3da6a8b6b84a930b702e9cb14418/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-firestore-sample/src/main/java/com/example/FirestoreSampleApp.java native lib sample has document reference example.

Comment: where as https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp/tree/e9c08349432e3da6a8b6b84a930b702e9cb14418/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-data-firestore-sample the Spring Data does not has example of document reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Spring Data is an open source framework and as an added abstraction, there might be some features missing. From the [source code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp/tree/e9c08349432e3da6a8b6b84a930b702e9cb14418/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-data-firestore-sample) and [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/current/reference/html/firestore.html) it does not look like there is a Document Reference feature present.

But  if you want, you can still use that feature by importing as a separate package `com.google.cloud.firestore.DocumentReference` as described in [this example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/e9c08349432e3da6a8b6b84a930b702e9cb14418/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-firestore-sample/src/main/java/com/example/FirestoreSampleApp.java#L59).